# SVG IMG has zero dimensions when floated in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, svg

I have a bit of a puzzler concerning an SVG used in an IMG tag in Firefox.

Codepens first:

1. http://codepen.io/doughamlin/pen/Fgosn
2. http://codepen.io/doughamlin/pen/zmBda

Codepen 1 uses SVG and does not work in Firefox (version 26). Codepen 2 uses a JPG and works correctly in Firefox. There are not other differences between the two. They both work correctly in Chrome, Safari and IE 10.

The inspector in Firefox shows 0 height and width for the SVG. The SVG displays normally if I remove the float:left from the H1 containing the IMG tag, but I have found no other way to make the SVG display not have I been able to figure out why the image would have 0 dimensions in the first place.

Is this just some obscure Firefox bug, or am I actually doing something wrong?

Comment: Couldn't these fiddles be reduced to just the one image for testing?

Comment: Indeed. I had originally thought it might be one of the elements around the image causing the issue but ruled that out. Meant to reduce the code before posting but got ahead of myself. They're reduced now.

Comment: It needs a width somewhere. If you add width 200px to the h1 that's floating then the image will show. If you add some text in the anchor, then the image will show. But it seems if the space only has the image it does not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This article will help you with why it does not work

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/SVG_Image_Tag

> There are some important things to take note of (referenced from the W3 specs):
>
> If you do not set the `x` or `y` attributes, they will be set to `0`.
>
> If you do not set the `height` or `width` attributes, they will be set to `0`.
>      Having a `height` or `width` attribute of `0` will disable rendering of the image.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I expected all images to be the same, but I can see why SVG would need dimensions explicitly defined. Max-width and max-height do not do the job (though min- does).

Comment: The linked resource is referring to `<image>` elements within an `<svg>` element, however the question is referring to an `<img>` element with its `src` attribute set to a `something.svg` file. This looks more like a bug in the way Firefox renders `<img>` elements.